# Create a stored procedure that returns the manager of an employee

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have done the following to create a stored procedure that returns the manager of an employee in the EMPLOYEE table:

[Additionally: REPORTSTO is a NUMBER value and contains the ID of the manager of the employee]

```
create or replace PROCEDURE MANAGER_OF_EMPLOYEE 
(
  THE_EMPLOYEEID IN NUMBER
)
AS 
  TEMP VARCHAR2(20);
  TEMP2 VARCHAR2(20);
  TEMP3 VARCHAR2(20);
  TEMP4 VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
  SELECT MGR.FIRSTNAME, MGR.LASTNAME, EMP.FIRSTNAME, EMP.LASTNAME INTO TEMP, TEMP2, TEMP3, TEMP4
  FROM EMPLOYEE EMP
  LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPLOYEE MGR 
  ON EMP.EMPLOYEEID = MGR.REPORTSTO
  WHERE EMP.EMPLOYEEID = THE_EMPLOYEEID AND EMP.REPORTSTO = MGR.EMPLOYEEID;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TEMP || ' ' || TEMP2 || ' IS THE MANAGER OF ' || TEMP3 || ' ' || TEMP4);
END MANAGER_OF_EMPLOYEE;
```

I always get 'Andrew Adams IS THE MANAGER OF Andrew Adams' no matter what I put as the parameter. Andrew Adams is the first row in the EMPLOYEE table and is the top manager so technically he IS his own manager. But why do I get the same output no matter what input I put?

Comment: I think your ON condition is wrong.   On Emp.Employee=Mgr.ReportsTo and later in the WHERE  you have Emp.ReportsTo=Mgr.EmployeeID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've gotten your join backwards.  This:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPLOYEE MGR 
ON EMP.EMPLOYEEID = MGR.REPORTSTO
```

Should be this:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPLOYEE MGR 
ON MGR.EMPLOYEEID = EMP.REPORTSTO
```

Once you correct this, you don't need anything in your WHERE clause except the `EMPLOYEEID = THE_EMPLOYEEID`.

Also, I wouldn't use a left join here, unless you have empty values in the `REPORTSTO` field that you want to include.  Just use an inner join.

Comment: Got it! Thank you!